# AngularJS 1: Filtering objects in the child ng-repeat loop with a property of the parent object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't get an expression to work as a filter parameter.

I have two objects arrays

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.clients = [
    {'client_id' : '1', 'client_name' : 'Anne'}, 
    {'client_id' : '2', 'client_name' : 'Tim'},
    {'client_id' : '3', 'client_name' : 'John'}
    ];
  
  $scope.courses = [
    {'ordered_by' : '1', 'course_name' : 'Marketing'}, 
    {'ordered_by' : '1', 'course_name' : 'Project Management'}, 
    {'ordered_by' : '1', 'course_name' : 'Analytics'}, 
    {'ordered_by' : '2', 'course_name' : 'Big Data'},
    {'ordered_by' : '2', 'course_name' : 'Data Visualization'},
    {'ordered_by' : '3', 'course_name' : 'PHP'}
    ];
});
```

Looping through them with the ng-repeat directive works fine, but I would like to be able to filter the nested loop with a value of a property of an object that is currently processed by the parent loop.

The code that's below lists all courses for each person as I don't know how to pass the client_id value to the filter of the nested directive.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Course list:</p>

  <div ng-repeat="person in clients">
    <strong><h2>{{person.client_name}} (ID: {{person.client_id}})</h2></strong>
    <ul>
      
      <!-- I wish it was this simple:
          <li ng-repeat="course in courses | filter : {'ordered_by' : '{{person.client_id}}' }"> -->

      <li ng-repeat="course in courses | filter : {'ordered_by' : '' }">
        {{course.course_name}}<br><span>(Ordered by person with the ID: {{course.ordered_by}})</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>


</body>
```

In the end output should be as follows:

> Anne (ID: 1)
>
> - Marketing
> - Project Management
> - Analytics
>
> Tim (ID: 2)
>
> - Big Data
> - Data Visualization
>
> John (ID: 3)
>
> - PHP

I would like to know if it's possible to do it this way or which direction I should be looking at.

Would passing a value of the property be possible with a custom filter?
Can expressions be used as filter parameters?

[Click here to see a working copy on Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/aqqrsGsCYfa4zWCmEBiO/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in clients">
  <strong><h2>{{person.client_name}} (ID: {{person.client_id}})</h2></strong>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="course in courses">
      <span ng-if="person.client_id === course.ordered_by">
        {{course.course_name}}
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

I only made a small correction to the code to have the ng-repeat and ng-if directives in the same element (to avoid empty <li> elements):

    <li ng-repeat="course in courses" ng-if="person.client_id === course.ordered_by">

Which gave the desired output. 

Thank you. I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: And to make it more efficient, you should move the logic (comparison) to your controller, and just have the ng-if reference your logic method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `ng-if` condition in your `ng-repeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="course in courses" ng-if="course.ordered_by == person.client_id">
  ...
</li>
```

[**Working Plunker here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/E7uuy2bfFyajHutAGREw?p=preview).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a better way to put `ng-if` in the `li` instead of a child `span` (as [@rrd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40723678/4927984) suggested), because it will reduce the number of elements created in the DOM